# SFTP Excecute Bit does not seem to be working correctly

Tags: permissions, ssh, ftp, sftp

I am trying to replace an existing FTP server and switch the users to be using sftp.

We have some strict requirements as far as permissions required on the folders.

For instance on the user's FTP Root (which is shared between several users with different permissions created with ACL) we have

```
/FolderA/FolderB
/FolderA/FolderC

User has x on FolderA
User has xr on FolderB
User has xw on FolderC
```

With FTP, user is able to CD to FolderA but not LS

User is able to CD and LS in FolderB as well as download files

User is able to CD but not LS on FolderC but is able to Upload files

I have set up SFTP for a new user and mounted FolderA in their (chrooted) home directory.
When I only have the x bit set it can NOT cd into any of the folders, I get Permission Denied. As soon as I set the r bit I CAN cd into the folder and obviously I am also able to ls however what I need is for the user to be able to cd into the folder but NOT ls it or read files from it.

I am using ACLs for my permissions, it looks like this

```
# file: FolderA
# owner: root
# group: root
user::rwx
user:NewUser:--x
group::---
other::---

# file: FolderB
# owner: root
# group: root
user::rwx
user:NewUser:r-x
group::---
other::---

# file: FolderC
# owner: root
# group: root
user::rwx
user:NewUser:-wx
group::---
other::---
```